# Stack Exchange mobile app - proposal for minor fix in UI design

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, ios-app

I haven't run into this issue in previous version of this app (iOS version of the app), but as of late I almost always hit the wrong button, in one particular situation, so I guess, that UI design has been slightly changed.

This is the image which can describe the issue:

[image: Stack Exchange mobile app UI]

"Back", button is too close to the "Upvote" button (or whatever is called by UI designers), so I find myself hitting the wrong button five of ten times. Which is a bit annoying. As I said, I don't remember that this was the issue in earlier versions...

I am using iPhone 6 which has relatively big screen, so I guess that this issue is more problematic on smaller phones like 4s...

I posted this proposal here on Meta, because according to the App Store, this should be the support page for StackExchange mobile app. I would kindly ask moderators to move this question to appropriate section, if doesn't belong here.

Comment: What mobile app? iOS or android?

Comment: Hi...An iOS app... I mentioned in my question that I am using iPhone 6...

Comment: So please tag properly in the future, mobile-app tag is for questions related to both apps in general.

Comment: @ShadowWizard Okay, no problem, thanks for pointing that.

Answer (score 3):

This will be fixed in 1.4.4.6, shipping to the review queue today.

The button will be at least 5pt lower and always centered rather than top aligned in the container.

Comment: Glad to hear that... Thanks for your response!